# Subtyping and Variance (&mut invariant) violate error in rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, variance, subtyping

```
fn main() {
    struct Foo<'a, T> {
        a: &'a mut T,
    }
    
    let p1 = 1;
    let mut p2 = &p1;
    {
        let p3 = 2;
        let mut p4 = &p3;
        let mut f = Foo {
            a: &mut p4,
        };
        f.a = &mut p2;
        println!("{}", f.a);
    }
    println!("{}", p2);
}
```

While run this program, it meets error such as:

```
error[E0597]: `p3` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:19
   |
10 |         let mut p4 = &p3;
   |                      ^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
16 |     }
   |     - `p3` dropped here while still borrowed
17 |     println!("{}", p2);
   |                    -- borrow later used here
```

```
-- borrow later used here
```

this is my first question: why exist these errors?

If I annotate the last line, such as :

```
fn main() {
    struct Foo<'a, T> {
        a: &'a mut T,
    }
    
    let p1 = 1;
    let mut p2 = &p1;
    {
        let p3 = 2;
        let mut p4 = &p3;
        let mut f = Foo {
            a: &mut p4,
        };
        f.a = &mut p2;
        println!("{}", f.a);
    }
    // println!("{}", p2);
}
```

It runs successfully. By refer to [rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html),

```
f.a = &mut p2;
```

&'a mut T is covariant over 'a and invariant over T, It should compile unsuccesfully. But successfully, why?

If I annotate the last line, It should compile unsuccesfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core of the problem is that `f` has a single fixed type `Foo<'a, &'b i32>` and by the variance rules for mutable references, `&'b i32` is invariant and thus `'b` is invariant.

However, `f` is used with `T` as two separate lifetimes via `p2` and `p4`. How does the compiler choose? Well it cannot shorten the lifetime used by `p2` into that of `p4`, because then `p2` can be modified to reference something of a smaller lifetime and thus `p2` can dangle at the last `println!` (consider what would happen if you added `*f.a = &p3;` right after assigning `f.a` to `&mut p2`). The only option is for the lifetime used by `p4` to be widened to match `p2`.

Since `p4` must match the lifetime of `p2`, the assignment from `p3` is now too short, so you get the error you see.

---

The second example works because the lifetime used by `p2` does not extend after the `println!` in the inner block, so `p3` can satisfy that lifetime.